# Is CleanMyMac really useful? or is it just placebo program?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I'm wondering if programs like CleanMyMac (http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) really help making my machine faster... I tried the demo version and it doesn't look like it does anything useful to me (I can empty the trash myself and empty caches from my browser).

If anything, I'm afraid that programs like this has bugs that might cause system instability... I thought Mac/Linux does not need this kind of things, is that correct?

Comment: Clearing browser caches is a great way to effectively make your machine slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't even have to go look and can tell you it is garbage--just from your description. You basically answered your own question: "it doesn't look like it does anything useful." Billion$ are made by crap-ware peddlers who sell to people who don't know how to do proper pc housekeeping themselves--and they don't really help after all.

Comment: Great, I suppose I just need confirmation from other people...

Answer (score 3):

Generally OS X doesn't need much in the way of maintenance.

Applejack (free) and DiskWarrior (not free) for when things get fouled up, Onyx (free) for cleaning caches, and FontNuke (free) for cleaning font caches. These are proven apps that do not harm your system, there are a lot of johnny come latelys and even some old titles (Spring Cleaning) trying to make a buck with software that is at best worthless.